# How to fix a Date format that changes in my GET URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel-5, get

I'm sending Date through a Get URL. Those dates are coming from my input in dd-mm-yyyy format but sent through the URL under mm-dd-yyyy format to much the bdd format.

Can you help to do the conversion and keep them as strings so I can use them in my query and where exactly I should do it, in my JS code or in the controller code?

**Update**

```
$('#CodeFinition').change(function(){
    var periode=$("#Période").val();
    var DebutFin = periode.split(' - ');
    var debut = DebutFin[0];
    var fin = DebutFin[1];
    debut =debut.replace(new RegExp('/', 'gi'),'-');
    fin =fin.replace(new RegExp('/', 'gi'),'-');
    var marque = $("#CodeMarque").val();
    var modele = $("#CodeModele").val();
    var finition = $("#CodeFinition").val();

    console.log(debut);

    $.ajax({
        url:'home/Calculer',
        method:"GET",
        data: {debut:debut, fin:fin, marque:marque, modele:modele, finition:finition},  //data body
        cache : false,
        async: true,
```

**debut** and **fin** are under dd-mm-yyyy format but I should send them under mm-dd-yyyy format so i can use them here :

```
  $marque = $request->get('marque');
        $modele = $request->get('modele');
        $finition = $request->get('finition');
        $debut = $request->get('debut');
        $fin =$request ->get('fin');



        echo $debut;
        echo $fin;

        $TotalAproduire = 100;

        $Commande = DB::connection('sqlsrv2')->table('Commande_nadine')
            ->join('finition','Commande_nadine.CodeFinition','=','finition.CodeFinition')
            ->whereDate('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',">",''.$debut.'')
            ->whereDate('Commande_nadine.DATE_DOCUMENT_CMD_ACHAT_FRS',"<",''.$fin.'')
            ->where('finition.CodeFinition',"=",$finition)
            ->where('finition.CodeModele','=',$modele)
            ->where('finition.CodeMarque','=',$marque)
            ->count('Commande_nadine.RECID_NADIN');
```

Comment: What you have tried till now ? code please ?

Comment: @CodeManiac Post updated

Comment: how about just split the string by `-` and join them again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the date with `-` and now join again according to your desired structure.

Here i swapped element of index `0` and `1` as you just wanted to interchange month and date.

```js
let str = `01-12-1994`
let dateArray = str.split('-')
let desiredDate = dateArray[1]+'-' + dateArray[0] + '-' + dateArray[2]

console.log(desiredDate)
```